# Is there any js library which replace the google chrome frame for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, modernizr, html5boilerplate

Is there any js library which replace the google chrome frame for IE.
I don't want my user to install google chrome frame...

Is there any js library I can add in my project and it just enhance the javascript redering of IE. Like we have **modernizr** & **html5boilerplate** to enhance the HTML and CSS.

Something similar for **Javascript**.

**Edited**
I have problem with IE javascript renderer .... lot of errors like

Unterminated string constant....

Object doesn't support this property or method...

and lot more all other browser working fine it just IE :(

Comment: Can you be more specific about what features IE doesn't support that you'd like to use in your application? Chrome Frame is only used to replace IE's renderer, and the default HTML5boilerplate only prompts to install it if they're running IE6.

Answer (score 0):

See [HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)